# No internet connection, problem with instaling drivers

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, drivers, internet

I have installed Linux Mint recently, and i have no internet connection.

```
ja@ja-X751LD:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for ja:   
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 37029  bytes 2631821 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37029  bytes 2631821 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


ja@ja-X751LD:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7800000-f7807fff

ja@ja-X751LD:~$ sudo lspci -nn
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I have downloaded compat-wireless-3.6.8 and backports-5.8-1, since from what I have learned from the internet, I don't have right drivers.
I wasn't able to install them. Results:

```
a@ja-X751LD:~/Pulpit/backports-5.8-1$ sudo make defconfig-brcmfmac
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
conf.c:6:10: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <locale.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [<builtin>: conf.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile.real:41: defconfig-brcmfmac] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:43: defconfig-brcmfmac] Error 2



ja@ja-X751LD:~/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1$ sudo make
[sudo] password for ja:   
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build M=/home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/compat/main.o
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:94,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:24,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.29.h:5,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:49,
                 from <command-line>:
./include/linux/bits.h:8: warning: "BIT" redefined
    8 | #define BIT(nr)   (UL(1) << (nr))
      | 
In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:24,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.29.h:5,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:49,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/bitops.h:6: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    6 | #define BIT(nr)   (1UL << (nr))
      | 
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:94,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:24,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.29.h:5,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:49,
                 from <command-line>:
./include/linux/bits.h:10: warning: "BIT_MASK" redefined
   10 | #define BIT_MASK(nr)  (UL(1) << ((nr) % BITS_PER_LONG))
      | 
In file included from ./include/linux/kernel.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:24,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.29.h:5,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:49,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/bitops.h:7: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    7 | #define BIT_MASK(nr)  (1UL << ((nr) % BITS_PER_LONG))
      | 
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:21,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:36,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from ./include/linux/timer.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:24,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.29.h:5,
                 from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:49,
                 from <command-line>:
./include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘cpumask_last’:
./include/linux/cpumask.h:225:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘find_last_bit’; did you mean ‘find_first_bit’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  225 |  return find_last_bit(cpumask_bits(srcp), nr_cpumask_bits);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         find_first_bit
In file included from /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/compat/main.c:1:
./include/linux/module.h: At top level:
./include/linux/module.h:127: warning: "module_init" redefined
  127 | #define module_init(initfn)     \
      | 
In file included from <command-line>:
/home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:29: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   29 | #define module_init(initfn)      \
      | 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/compat/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:522: /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1/compat] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /home/ja/Pulpit/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:84: modules] Error 2
```

I'm rather green, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried to install C libraries next, but my computer says that it has better version of libc6, and to install glibc, it seems I need bitutilis, with gives me

```
ja@ja-X751LD:~/Pulpit/binutils-2.35$ sudo ./configure
[sudo] password for ja:   
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/ja/Pulpit/binutils-2.35':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Contents of config.log, thought i have no idea if this is even relevant.

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ja-X751LD
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.4.0-26-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2390: checking build system type
configure:2404: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2451: checking host system type
configure:2464: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2484: checking target system type
configure:2497: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2551: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2619: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2630: checking whether ln works
configure:2652: result: yes
configure:2656: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2660: result: yes
configure:2667: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2731: result: /bin/sed
configure:2740: checking for gawk
configure:2756: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2767: result: gawk
configure:4106: checking for gcc
configure:4122: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4133: result: gcc
configure:4362: checking for C compiler version
configure:4371: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4382: $? = 0
configure:4371: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 
configure:4382: $? = 0
configure:4371: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4382: $? = 1
configure:4371: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4382: $? = 1
configure:4402: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4424: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4428: $? = 1
configure:4466: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4471: error: in `/home/ja/Pulpit/binutils-2.35':
configure:4473: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='gawk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBDEBUGINFOD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='./configure'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-libcpp build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='pc'
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl libelf libiconv libctf texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gdbserver gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools libcc1 gotools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
get_gcc_base_ver=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-liboffloadmic target-libhsail-rt target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-libffi target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_subdir='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_vendor='pc'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

I have no idea what to do next. My end goal is to have working internet connection, preferable wireless. I believe i will be able to install with apt-get then.
I also should have Ethernet, but I was only able to find any mention of it in bios as device.

Please, help.

Comment: I bet you're on a laptop/notebook. Look for the firmware that is probably missing. Run `sudo journalctl -b -p err` and look for it. This works on Debian, not sure about Mint, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this ? There are some paths to explore.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

I suggest to perform searches with

```
 PC_model_number    mint_version    BCM143142
```